# where can I find the login block to modify?

Tags: 7, users

I want to modify login block!Where can I see login block ?

I am using danland theme in drupal 7 site. So far I have walked through `sites/all/themes/page.tpl.php` file, `node.tpl.php` and `template.php` file, but I didn't find.

Can anyone help me in this ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: goto `admin/structure/blocks` here you will find login block placed in region.

Comment: @WaQaR: I want to modify the code, so i want to go through root of the files

Comment: What do you want to modify? please edit and update your question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps for customizing login block available in Drupal.

1) Go to your template.php file for the theme you're working on. Should be in the root of the theme folder for your theme

2) Now check for the below mentioned function in your template.php file. if its not exist then create it and if its exists then append the below mentioned code in the same.

```
function yourthemenamehere_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   $hooks['user_login_block'] = array(
     'template' => 'templates/user-login-block',
     'render element' => 'form',
   );
   return $hooks;
 }
function yourthemenamehere_preprocess_user_login_block(&$vars) {
  $vars['name'] = render($vars['form']['name']);
  $vars['pass'] = render($vars['form']['pass']);
  $vars['submit'] = render($vars['form']['actions']['submit']);
  $vars['rendered'] = drupal_render_children($vars['form']);
}
```

Now save and close!

3) Now in side your theme directory there will be a folder called "template". if its not there please create it there only and then create a php file inside that folder called: "user-login-block.tpl.php"
Inside this file, put the following code:

```
<div id="user-login-block-container">
  <div id="user-login-block-form-fields">
    <?php print $name; // Display username ?>
    <?php print $pass; // Display Password ?>
    <?php print $submit; // Display submit ?>
    <?php print $rendered; // Display hidden elements (required for successful login) ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="/user/register">Singup</a> OR <a href="/user/password">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

4) IMPORTANT STEP , navigate to "admin/config/development/performance" and click "clear all caches" -- this is critical because only after deleting cache you can able to see the changes in your login block.

Now you can change the stucture of user-login-block.tpl.php as your wish.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: PHP Weblineindia: seems you have given the answer in detail , becuase when we click on logini wanted to add a request new password link tab ,  i really appriciate, before that if i add this code will it make any changes like adding and removing block on user login page ?any how i will be very thankful if it works, million thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all if you think this answer has helped you in any manner then you can always appreciate us by up voting the answer. Now to answer your question regarding effects of this code, it will not make any difference in the login page it will effect only to the block rather login block which can be displayed any region.

Comment: PHP Weblineindia :Thanks,i did as you suggested, but the request new password tab is not showing when we click on login link.:(though href="/user/password">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>  is exist in code

Comment: When you click on Forgot Password link where it will bring you to?

I have checked it and its taking me to the "Request New Password" tab.

Comment: forgot password link is not showing,please check the screen shot above.even i tried to inspect the element and tried to add below code                                <div class="tabs">
<h2 class="element-invisible">Primary tabs</h2><ul class="tabs primary"><li><a href="/mcms/user/register">Create new account</a> <a href="/mcmss/user/password">Forgot Password</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="/mcms/user" class="active">Log in<span class="element-invisible">(active tab)</span></a></li>
</ul>           
</div>  in user-login-block.tpl file  but its no use:(

Comment: its not showing that reset password link tab  on loginpage,

Comment: in login page i could not see the request new password link tab why is this?iam breaking my head like anything, please if you know ,please suggest me:(

Comment: I think there would be any module which can create this problem to your user login block, other wise in the basic theme Request new password link is showing by default. I am also having above mentioned code in many sites and it works perfect for me.

Comment: how to over come from this problem, ?any idea? i will be very thankfull